# Missing classes android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, cardview, gradle-dependencies

I have build Text Recognition App from this [tutoriel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmuz8qIWcL8) but my layout giving me some issue

The following classes could not be found:

> android.support.v7.widget.CardView

[Expectation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfGa7.png)

[Reality current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic8SY.png)

What Im I missing or doing wrong ?

**build.gradle app** :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            app:cardElevation="3dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Result"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/resultET"
                    android:hint=""
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autofillHints=""/>
            </LinearLayout>
      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside replacing

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0
```

as

```
androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0
```

you still need to replace xml and import object from

```
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

to

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

By the way, other components should be replaced too.
for example:

in gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

in code and xml object will be

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing your project under androidx replace

```
implementation 'android.support.v7.widget.CardView'
```

with

```
implementation'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Comment: forgot to tell you the need to replacement of all widget relevant

Answer (score 0):

In Java - You can now use

> import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

In build.gradle -

> implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

Comment: Incase you are not using 
android.useAndroidX=true And android.enableJetifier=true
Please use these in gradle.properties file.

Also you are getting this error at runtime or compile time. Please mention that also.